What are the restrictions for objects targeted by Glyph of Warding?
To trigger an object glyph, a creature must "open" the object:

This powerful inscription harms those who enter, pass, or open the warded area or object....

But also, the caster can "set all of the conditions":

You set all of the conditions of the ward. Typically, any creature entering the warded area or opening the warded object without speaking a password (which you set when casting the spell) is subject to the magic it stores.

So if a caster wanted to store a number of different effects in a small container, are their options limited to small, openable objects? Or does the "set all the conditions" clause allow you to glyph pebbles that pop when they hit the ground?
Extra Credit: if the small object must be openable, could you cast glyph of warding on an egg?

Glyph of warding specifies the conditions the caster can set
When the glyph of warding spell description, in part, says, "You set all of the conditions of the ward," that's the paragraph's topic sentence. What follows in that paragraph are the conditions that are under the caster's control to set:

You set all of the conditions of the ward. Typically, any creature entering the warded area or opening the warded object without speaking a password (which you set when casting the spell) is subject to the magic it stores. [The default condition.] Alternatively or in addition to a password trigger, glyphs can be set according to physical characteristics (such as height or weight) or creature type, subtype, or kind. [Other conditions under the caster's control to set.] Glyphs can also be set with respect to good, evil, law, or chaos, or to pass those of your religion. [Still more conditions that the caster can set.] They cannot be set according to class, HD, or level. [A caster can't pick these conditions.] Glyphs respond to invisible creatures normally but are not triggered by those who travel past them ethereally. [Conditions for triggering conditions.] Multiple glyphs cannot be cast on the same area. However, if a cabinet has three different drawers, each can be separately warded.[And clarifying conditions for placement. Emphasis and editorializing mine.]

That topic sentence's expansive opening claim—"You set all of the conditions of the ward"—does not mean that the caster can fabricate his own conditions and what follows are merely suggestions or examples. That topic sentence is introducing the idea of conditions that it immediately after defines. Yes, that sucks, and you have my sympathy. Pathfinder's tendency to make grandiose claims about a game element in one sentence then dashing the reader's hopes in the next is well-documented and deeply irritating—cf. here. (I imagine this tendency being an especially heavy burden on those coming to Pathfinder from a language other than English. Absent a thorough understanding of typical US English language discourse patterns, Pathfinder probably seems chock full of lies.)
To be clear, the caster can't concoct conditions that aren't specified by the conditions listed in that paragraph above then set those—let's call them—secret conditions because the spell descriptions says that the caster "set[s] all of the conditions of the ward." No. Instead, there just aren't other conditions to set. The caster's stuck with what the spell says, not free to extrapolate from what the spell doesn't say. (But, to be fair, that's a lot more fun.)
Thus, yes, if a caster wanted to apply several different glyphs to a lone container, that container can have only one glyph per openable access point. A miniature chest of drawers could have one glyph per miniature drawer, for instance. On the other hand, if the caster wants to ward an area, then the caster places the glyph somewhere within that defined area (i.e. up to 5 sq. ft. per caster level) and an appropriate creature entering that area will set off the glyph. That's it.
This means that, according to the spell's Target or Area entry, a caster can put a glyph on a typical pebble, for instance, but that pebble isn't an area so it won't ward an area, and—unless making specious argument like, for instance, "Anything can be opened once with enough force"—a typical pebble can't be opened. The spell will have no effect.
You don't open eggs; you break them. Putting a glyph on a typical creature's egg is usually pointless. An eggshell has no opening until it's broken by the creature within. Afterward, that opening can't—by most definitions—be closed (so as to then be a viable target of the glyph spell) then opened again (so as to trigger the glyph). Still, talk to the GM; although their success rate so far has been low, perhaps in the campaign all the king's horses and all the king's men will finally be able to put the broken egg back together again.
